# Can Jacoco test coverage be extended to UiAutomator and Robotium?

Tags: android, unit-testing, automated-tests

Jacoco test coverage can be used with the unit test cases but can it be used to know the test coverage done using the robotium or UiAutomator.

Comment: check this https://medium.com/@sergiygrechukha/android-ui-and-unit-tests-coverage-report-with-jacoco-and-sonarqube-1db5576f79b0